# Child UIView Width

Tags: uiview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I've been developing apps in Xamarin Studio for ios devices (iPad, iPhone, iPod) and I have a problem regarding child UIViews width. I want a child UIView to have the same width as its parent, but I am unable to figure out how to do it. I am using Auto Layout on my screens setting the necessary constraints, but this only keeps my widgets on screen organized (it doesn't auto resize anything for different screen sizes on iPhone). Can someone help me achieve this? I need UIView same width as its parent.

[This is how the screen looks on iPhone 6 plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsA8r.jpg)

[This is how the screen looks on iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsojF.jpg)

Comment: Does it output some constraint errors in the output console, if you debug?

Comment: Nope, everything seems in order. If I run the app on iPad with different screen sizes the layout adjusts well, but for iPhones the elements don't resize properly.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Do you add the constraints in code or in the designer?

Comment: I am adding the constraints through Xamarin designer.  I will send screenshots in a few.

Comment: I edited my original post and added screenshots.  You can see that the AutoLayout is working correctly, but my child UIViews don't have same width as its parent.

Comment: uhhm sorry. I don't get it ^^ wich childviews? the icons?

Comment: or is this blue border the root view?

Comment: Its ok.  The bottom icons are inside a UIView, and the top image is also inside a UIView (both UIViews have a white background and those are the child views).  The one with purpleish background would be the parent UIview.

Comment: Are you wanting the Bottom icons container and Top image view container to keep the same width as the parent view?

Comment: yes, that would be it.

Comment: is the xib somewhere available?

Comment: Would you be able to tell us what constraint you have on these views? e.g. Leading Trailing to the superview not in relation to the margin or equal widths to the superview? should force it to adapt to different screen sizes

Comment: @IainSmith I have none of those constraints. I currently have Align Center x and Y, and Height.  I was looking how to achieve the leading and trailing constraints in Xamarin, but still couldn't fix this.  How can I achieve this in Xamarin? I don't see any of those options if I decide to edit a certain constraint.

Comment: Any luck with using Interface builder? with the step in the answer below?

Comment: @IainSmith Hi Iain, your response was very useful.  I have my child views match its parent width.  Thanks a lot! I will continue to apply these constraints on the rest of my view controllers.

Comment: No worries Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be Honest, I normally do constraints in Xcode as it is easier. Right click on your nib and select `Open With` > `Xcode Interface Builder`

Then once your nib is open `ctrl` click and drag from your top container view to the superview and select `Equal Widths` then do the same for `Leading space to container`, `Top space to container`, for height `ctrl` click drag on to itself(top container view) and set the height.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

If you're having difficulties it might be best to upload the nib to github so I can have a look.